# SQL "NOT IN" for some reason not working..?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SQL statement is not working:

```
SELECT  stock.IdStock
        ,stock.Descr       
FROM    [Inventory].[dbo].[Stock] stock
WHERE   stock.IdStock NOT IN
        (SELECT foreignStockId FROM
         [Subset].[dbo].[Products])
```

Comment: error?????????????????????????

Comment: Define `Not Working`.  Error messages; if so, what error message?  Unexpected output; if so, give examples of the input data, what you got and what you expected.

Comment: Probably you have a `NULL foreignStockId` in `Products`

Comment: Your syntax is for SQL Server, why did you tag it with MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably returns a `NULL`. Try

```
SELECT  stock.IdStock
        ,stock.Descr       
FROM    [Inventory].[dbo].[Stock] stock
WHERE   stock.IdStock NOT IN
        (SELECT foreignStockId FROM
         [Subset].[dbo].[Products]
         WHERE foreignStockId IS NOT NULL )
```

I normally use NOT EXISTS for this type of query

```
SELECT stock.idstock,
       stock.descr
FROM   [Inventory].[dbo].[Stock] stock
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   [Subset].[dbo].[Products] p
                   WHERE  p.foreignstockid = stock.idstock)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably

```
SELECT foreignStockId FROM
         [Subset].[dbo].[Products]
```

Query returns at least one NULL Value

try EXISTS

```
SELECT  stock.IdStock
        ,stock.Descr       
FROM    [Inventory].[dbo].[Stock] stock
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM [Subset].[dbo].[Products] 
         where stock.IdStock =foreignStockId )
```